# Missing ASP.NET Core Web Application Template and all ASP.Net Core Templates in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I do have a very odd problem with Visual Studio 2019 (Professional version 16.9.2) when trying to create a new project with a *ASP.NET Core Web Application* template.

Although I have a a lot of templates available, my list of new project is desperately not showing the template, and none of ASP.Net Core ones (the ones with the little planet, a circle and a blue dot icon) [this is the icon I don't have, it's not taken  from my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EN7n.jpg)

My version of VS is up to date, I've installed the *.NET Core cross-platform development* [my Visual Studio configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjaGc.jpg)

I've installed the .NET Core package (I tried with all versions).

No matter which option I'm chosing in the Update tool, I still have the same list of templates, it never changes.

I've reinstalled VS from scatch. I've tried on 4 different machines (1 physical machine, 1 virtual desktop and 2 servers). I've also tried from line command prompt by using dotnet new, but I do have exactly the same list then the one in VS.

I've also tried to change the templates location from my local profile folder to the C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates
But the templates list remains the same.

I'm out of ideas, sounds like I tried almost everything, for now I'm stuck!

If anyone among you has any idea or already had this issue, please let me know!

Thanks everyone for any help you could grant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to have the 'missing' template. It seems that in VS 2019 the *ASP.NET Core Web Application template* has been replaced by the *ASP.NET Core Empty*.
I had to tweak it a little, but seems to be now Ok.

I hope this helps some folks

Comment: What do you have to tweak in order to have the missing template?

Answer (score 1):

Aparently, by design, in .net 8, the angular and react templates are also missing. It seems they aren't going to be back either.

If you want to create a new Angular project without installing Visual Studio add ins, you can create one with the dotnet CLI. Instead of running `dotnet new angular` like you would last year, you now need to create angular projects in a slightly different way. Run the following commands in your CMD/Terminal:

```
# You probably don't have the 'x' tool yet
dotnet tool install -g x

# Create a new angular project
x new angular-spa ProjectName
```

However, what is interesting, is that the project structure is (i.m.o.) quite different from the .net 6 / .net 7 `dotnet new angular`. They've built in ServiceStack by default. (Which i did not know, would anyone know why they've done that?)

Source: https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-spa

Hope this helps anyone!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Install the ASP.NET and web development workload.

Visual Studio Installer -> Click on Modify -> Select **ASP.NET and web development** workload.
[image: ASP.NET and web development]